# How can I keep the same size of the objects of a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to keep the size of the objects of a HTML page can be kept no matter the size of the window of the web browser used.  I tried to play with the height and width in the classes but even with that, it doesn't work.

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you create a minimal reproducible  example of your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want your elements to respect `width` and `height` CSS properties they must have a block `display` property such as `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use constant values like pixels instead of percents.

You can give a heigth and with of 20px to your element and it will stay 20px no matter what the size of the window is.